# How to set runtime license key on ActiveX object from .NET

Tags: .net, activex, factory

I'm trying to load an ActiveX COM object into a .NET project. It uses licensing (ie FACTORY2). Things work fine on the development machine since the Design License is available.  But of course I need to se the runtime license so it will load on other machines.

I'm stuck on how to set the runtime license.  I have imported the COM object as an interop and create it like:

```
Private _myObject As MyComLib.ObjectClass
_myObject = new MyCom.ObjectClass
```

However without the Design License I get the error "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040112"

How do I force the Interop to provide the runtime license (and use IClassFactory2?)???

The only help I've found is a page on MSDN http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326651 that imports the COM object as an Active X import (aximp).  However this hasn't been successful yet so hoping there's a more straightforward way...

Comment: Gave up on the dynamic loading and just load the object statically as an ActiveX - should have done this to start with...